# Erlang binary pattern matching fails

Tags: binary, erlang, pattern-matching, binaries

Why does this issue a badmatch error?  I can't figure out why this would fail:

```
<<IpAddr, ":*:*">> = <<"2a01:e34:ee8b:c080:a542:ffaf:*:*">>.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern matching of a binary proceeds left-to-right so it will match `IpAddr` first before it tries the following segment. There is no back-tracking until there is a match. A default typed variable like `IpAddr` matches one byte. See [Bit Syntax Expressions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id77874) and [Bit Syntax](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html) for a proper description and more examples.

As alternative to using pattern matching here you might consider using the `binary` module. There are two functions which could be useful to you: `binary:match/2/3` and `binary:split/2/3`. These search which may better fit your problem.

As a last alternative you could try using regular expressions and the `re` module.

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the size of `IpAddr` so that it can be pattern-matched:

```
1> <<IpAddr:28/binary, ":*:*">> = <<"2a01:e34:ee8b:c080:a542:ffaf:*:*">>.
<<"2a01:e34:ee8b:c080:a542:ffaf:*:*">>
2> IpAddr.
<<"2a01:e34:ee8b:c080:a542:ffaf">>
```

Comment: What if the size is variable?

Comment: That won't happen in this case, right? If so, the number of bytes can also be read from a variable: `IpAddr:IpLength/binary`.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case it can as the number of characters in eacg segment can vary.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla I don't think erlang can do this. It will error with IpLength is unbound.